# Socket.io not emitting/receiving events while using namespaces

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, coffeescript, socket.io

I have the following code written in coffeescript that makes use of socket.io and node.js in the server side

**Server**

```
io.of("/room").authorization (handshakeData, callback) ->
    #Check if authorized
    callback(null,true)
.on 'connection',  (socket) ->
    console.log "connected!"

    socket.emit 'newMessage', {msg: "Hello!!", type: 1} 

    socket.on 'sendMessage', (data) ->
        @io.sockets.in("/room").emit 'newMessage', {msg: "New Message!!", type: 0}
```

**Client**

```
socket = io.connect '/'

socket.of("/room")
    .on 'connect_failed',  (reason) ->
    console.log 'unable to connect to namespace', reason
.on 'connect', ->
    console.log 'sucessfully established a connection with the namespace'

socket.on 'newMessage', (message) ->
    console.log "Message received: #{message.msg}"
```

My problem is that after I started using namespaces the communication between server and client has stopped working. I didn't find any working example similar to this so I might be doing something wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Namespaces aren't used on the client like they are used server side. Your client side code should connect directly to the namespace path like this:

```
var socket = io.connect('/namespace');
socket.on('event', function(data) {
  // handle event
});
```

That being said, namespaces are different than rooms. Namespaces are joined on the client side, while rooms are joined on the server side. Therefore this code won't work:

```
io.sockets.in('/namespace').emit('event', data);
```

You have to either reference the namespace, or call it from the global `io` object.

```
var nsp = io.of('/namespace');
nsp.emit('event', data);

// or get the global reference
io.of('/namespace').emit('event', data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer that helped me to understand how the namespaces work, but I have problems when I try to authorize a connection into a namespace. I try to follow a example from the socket.io wiki (https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing#namespace-authorization) and I fail while emitting/receiving events. Connection seems to be successful because the event is triggered  as "connected" and  "sucessfully established a connection with the namespace" messages are shown in client and server logs

Comment: As you can see in the server side I'm using the socket received as parameter on 'connection' event.
In client side I'm using the same object as used to connect to server

Comment: Thanks!! Now is everything working. The wiki was a bit confusing and I mixed some code I took from there with yours!

Comment: How does the socket know what url/port to connect to?

Comment: @SomethingOn The namespace is just a path. If you need a URL or port, just specify it like so: `io.connect('http://example.com:8080/namespace')`.